# Set tooltip for Infragistics UltraWinToolbars ControlContainerTool

Tags: winforms, controls, tooltip, infragistics

How do I display a tool tip for a `ControlContainerTool` when using Infragistics `UltraToolbarsManager`? I am able to set the `ControlContainerTool.SharedProps.ToolTipText` property but it is not displayed.

Comment: Use the UltraTipManager :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the ControlContainerTool you will need to set the tooltip on the control that is used within the tool since that is what the mouse is actually over.  You can use either the UltraToolTipManager or the Microsoft ToolTip for this.